# Notification do nothing when clicked

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

So I would like to create a notification that, when clicked, will open my MainActivity and do something according to the extras I've put in the intent.

Right now, the notification works perfectly, but once I click it, nothing happens. I've search a little bit and have done some modification to my code :

I have added `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to my activity in the manifest.

I have put the code to execute in my MainActivity in the onNewIntent method :

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    System.out.println("Entering onNewIntent!!!!!!!");

    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
        System.out.println("URL in Main Activity : " + url);
        if (url != null && url != "") {
            saveFile(url);
            dezipFile();
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing changed, I've put some System.out to see if it even reach the beginning of the onNewIntent... But nothing is shown on the console.

Here is the code where I create the notification :

```
   private void createNotification () {

    Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    downloadIntent.putExtra("url", url);
    downloadIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent downloadPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, downloadIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "Notif")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notif)
            .setContentTitle(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.notif_title))
            .setContentText(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.notif_content))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(downloadPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notification_download", "Dowload BD infos", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        builder.setChannelId("notification_download");
    }

    NotificationManagerCompat notification = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
    notification.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

If anybody knows what I did wrong, it will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "Notif")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notif)
        .setContentTitle(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.notif_title))
        .setContentText(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.notif_content))
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        .setContentIntent(downloadPendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true);


 Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
    mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(mIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks! I modified my intent and my PendingIntent and created the TaskStackBuilder and this worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the activity launched when user clicks on a notification as follows:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, targetActivityClass);
Intent backIntent = new Intent(this, backActivityClass);
Intent[] intentArray = new Intent[]{backIntent, resultIntent};

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 0, intentArray,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);    
builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

This code also sets the activity launched when user clicks the back button after clicking the notification.